# Setting Test environment variables in rails without putting in source code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, test-environments

I'm using Twilio for an app and on production I set the auth token using heroku's CLI. I'm using `sms-spec` (https://github.com/monfresh/sms-spec) to test my app's Twilio integration locally. I want to set `ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']` to my token in the test environment.

I use guard to auto-run my tests whenever I make changes so I don't want to have to manually set the ENV variable each time I run tests. I also don't want to put the token in my source code for security reasons.

Is there a way I can set the ENV variable for my local test environment such that it is permanent and not in my source? I've spent a few hours researching this and can't seem to find a good explanation of how to do this. Any help is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two approaches:

1. Use a gem like `Dotenv` ([link](https://github.com/bkeepers/dotenv)).  This is the approach I use in most of my applications for development.  Simply include the gem in your gemfile, bundle install and then store any environment variable settings in a top level file called `.env`.  Restart your rails server and ENV will be automatically loaded.  Very easy to use and convenient.
2. If you are flexible on the ENV part, and you are running Rails 4.1+, you can use `config/secrets/yml`.  This is documented very well in the [Rails 4.1 release notes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/4_1_release_notes.html), Section 2.2.  So, in your case, you would set it up like so:

   development:
     twilio_auth_token: verysecretstring

Then, in your initializer, instead of referencing `ENV['TWILIO_AUTH_TOKEN']`, you would use `Rails.application.secrets.twilio_auth_token`.  I haven't tried this myself, but it is on my list as I would rather use native Rails functionality than a separate gem.

Of course, any files which contain your secrets needs to be safeguarded carefully.  At a minimum, make sure you include in `.gitignore` so that your secrets do not find their way into your code respository.